# Pay back the 2008 First-Time homebuyers credit with a certain amount?

Tags: united-states, taxes, first-time-home-buyer, irs

I repaid 500 on 2010 Tax return for the 2008 First-Time Homebuyers credit, but do I have to pay 500 on each return or just make sure it is paid of within 15 years.  For example, can I chose to pay 0 this year (2011) and pay 1000 next year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you live in the house (its your primary residence), you must pay $500 a year, *no skipping*.

Once you sell, or rent out - you must repay in full the remaining amount.

[IRS pub on that](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=186831,00.html).

Comment: Thanks, I also called the IRS and confirmed this as well.

Comment: Wow.. did not know it was considered an interest-free loan!

Comment: @CheckRaise only for purchases in 2008. If you bought your home during 2009 and 2010 and got the credit - you do not need to pay it back.

Comment: Ah, a year makes all the difference! Whew!

Comment: I don't understand how they can call it a credit and make you pay it back :(

Comment: @Xaisoft the money was given as a tax credit.